# Returning all records from a two step has_many relationship in a one liner

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

*Disclaimer: Sorry for the weird title, couldn't find an appropiate one. Also, the following code is just a fast example, I apologize for not following the conventions by the book.*

So in the example I just want to get all the clothes in a house in an `Array`. Given that cloth belongs to person, and person belongs to house, I did as follows:

```
def clothes
  clothes = []
  current_house.people.each do |person|
    person << person.clothes
  end
  clothes
end
```

Is there any approach in Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2 to make this method a **one liner**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one liner is:

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clothes, :through => :people
end
```

Then you can just call:

```
 current_house.clothes
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to define a new `clothes` association in the `House` model, you can still do something like this:

```
def clothes
  current_house.people.collect{ |p| p.clothes }.flatten
end
```

But I strongly advise to choose BroiSatse's solution to define a new association.

Comment: I don't have a problem defining another association but this things are nice to know to write clean code in other situations, thank you!

Comment: You can even write it shorter: `cuurent_house.people.collect(&:clothes).flatten`. The bigest issue here is n+1 problem, so I would add `includes(:clothes)` between people and collect

Comment: `flat_map(&:clothes)` will be shorter